# Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, jackson-databind, spring-framework-beans

Getting exception when trying to run spring boot app.
I am trying to upgrade spring-kafka from 2.2.6 to 2.4.1.
I am using spring-boot 2.2.6, spring-kafka 2.4.1 and spring-core 5.2.5. Tried downgrading jackson to 2.10.3 but still the same issue.

```
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0                    

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.walmart.asda.userlists.UserlistsApplication.main(UserlistsApplication.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0                    

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper.builder(JsonMapper.java:114)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.JacksonUtils.enhancedObjectMapper(JacksonUtils.java:58)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.JacksonUtils.enhancedObjectMapper(JacksonUtils.java:47)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.<init>(DefaultKafkaHeaderMapper.java:100)
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.<init>(MessagingMessageConverter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.<init>(KafkaTemplate.java:76)
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.<init>(KafkaTemplate.java:91)
    at com.walmart.intl.userlists.infrastructure.kafka.config.KafkaMessageProducerConfigure.userListKafkaProducerTemplate(KafkaMessageProducerConfigure.java:52)
    at com.walmart.intl.userlists.infrastructure.kafka.config.KafkaMessageProducerConfigure$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a6536a0.CGLIB$userListKafkaProducerTemplate$0(<generated>)
    at com.walmart.intl.userlists.infrastructure.kafka.config.KafkaMessageProducerConfigure$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a6536a0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b5212b4e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at com.walmart.intl.userlists.infrastructure.kafka.config.KafkaMessageProducerConfigure$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5a6536a0.userListKafkaProducerTemplate(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 74 more
```

My pom.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.walmart.asda.userlists</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserLists-Service</artifactId>
    <version>3.75-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>UserLists-Service</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.version>5.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.boot.version>2.2.6.RELEASE<spring.boot.version>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jaxrs.version>2.0-m10</jaxrs.version>
        <jackson.version>2.11.0</jackson.version>
        
        
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp.esapi/esapi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxrs.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- kafka dependency -->

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
           <version>2.4.1.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
           <version>2.4.1.RELEASE</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
        
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.openpojo/openpojo -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.openpojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>openpojo</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Does anybody know why is the root cause of this and how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you trying to outsmart the starter dependency management? Ditch your jackson dependencies (already part of `spring-boot-starter-web`) You are also mixing jackson 1 and Jackson 2 which is trouble waiting to happen. Remove the `spring-beans` dependency and I strongly suggest to ditch the `spring.version` as well (spring boot manages that for you). Ditch `javax.validation` and use `spring-boot-starter-validation` instead. Spring Boot already manages kafka, so you can ditch the version, if you want a different want set `spring-kafka.version` to the one you want. Finally upgrade Spring Boot

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. It worked.